# regex to valiadte a string with alphanumeric and but no identical characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am working on a regex to validate a string that,

- contains alphanumeric value
- does not contain identical characters more than 4 times in a row (like **aaaaa** or **222222**)
- total length should be between 6 to 15

I am using the following regex, but it doesn't work for the input => ***String1bbbbb***

```
/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=\S*[A-Z])(?=\S*[0-9])(?!.*[\w{4,}])[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,15}+$/i


if(preg_match('/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=\S*[A-Z])(?=\S*[0-9])(?!.*[\w{4,}])[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,15}+$/i', $string)) {
    echo "Valid String";
} else {
    echo "invalid String";
}
```

using negative look ahead to validate the identical characters  like below

> (?!.*[\w{4,}])

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give us a [regex101](http://regex101.com) with positive and negative test cases, please? My taking your code and applying it [here](https://regex101.com/r/rR8iN4/1) isn't giving any valid results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

`^(?=.{6,15}$)(?:([A-Za-z0-9])\1{0,3}(?!\1))+$`

This will make sure length is between 6 and 15, it will capture the character, possibly repeated up to 3 more times and then it will make sure the same character does not get repeated again in the next position. Here you have it in regex101: https://regex101.com/r/aO7pM5/1